# Applying boundary conditions to counting combinatorial question

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, inclusion-exclusion, integer-partitions

I was trying to count the number of natural number solutions to the equation: $x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_{11} = 20$, such that $0 \leq x_i \leq 9$, for all $i \in \{1, ..., 11\}$.

I know how to apply the first boundary condition - if I only required $0 \leq x_i$, then the number of solutions is $$\frac{30!}{20!\cdot10!}$$ because I can interpret the problem as trying to arrange $20$ balls in between $10$ bars, including the possibility of having $0$ balls in between two given bars. I just don't know how to apply the latter condition, i.e. $x_i \leq 9$.

Could anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Inclusion-exclusion based on whether or not any upper bound conditions are violated.  In particular, if the first upper bound condition were violated for instance (*among possibly more*), then you are in the scenario of $10\leq x_1$ and $0\leq x_i$ for each other $i$.  Through a change of variable, letting $y_1=x_1-10$ and $y_i=x_i$ for the rest, you should be able to solve for the number of solutions to this new system of $y_i$'s in the same way that you did for the original system.  Note in particular that you can violate multiple upper bound conditions simultaneously.

Comment: @RobPratt Thank you, I think it does! It’s a deeper explanation of what JMoravitz suggested, and I believe I understand it now!

Answer (score 0):

**Big Hint:**

To divide 5 into 4 parts none of which is larger than 2 (or negative), can be done in following ways (ignoring permutations)

$2,2,1,0$

$2,1,1,1$

Consider $(x^0+x^1+x^2)^4$. Then $x^5$ would be formed from terms like $x^2.x^2.x^1.x^0$ and $x^2.x^1.x^1.x^1$ only. In how many ways? Obviously that's the strength of the coefficient.